# Replacing values from a column with RegEx in Oracle

Tags: jquery, sql, regex, oracle

I need edit the values of a column in Oracle database. In this, the values follow a pattern:

`123456789X`

The modification requires the following change:

- add six 0's
- add blank space between the 0's and the X

`123456789000000        X`

I need make this change with a pattern or RegExp in a single query.

Thanks

Comment: What is the pattern? Please provide more details.

Comment: The pattern of the column is  indicated in quotation marks, values that follow the same pattern but to which you want to add and more values (somes 0's and blanks).

Comment: Still insufficient information to provide a solution

Comment: @MarcusStern So, what if the string was `Qwerty1234X` or `Fred` or ...? What is the algorithm from changing the input string into the output string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace` function to convert the string.

It's on you to define the appropriate conversion rule, e.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Qwerty123456X', 
'([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])', -- Rule : Digit followed by Number 
'\1<bla>\2') CITY -- insert <bla> between
FROM DUAL;

---> Qwerty123456<bla>X
```